# how to get return value from prompt input box? C# win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created prompt input box in which user enter two values and press button and i want to return values on button click and get these values in other method.
Here is my code

```
  public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
    {
        Form prompt = new Form()
        {
            Width = 500,
            Height = 150,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
            Text = caption,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        };
        Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 10, Text = text };
        Label textLabel2 = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 55, Text = text };
        textLabel2.Text = "Replace with";
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 70, Width = 200 };
        TextBox textBox2 = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 30, Width = 200 };


        Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Replace", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
        confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
        prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
        prompt.Controls.Add(textBox2);
        prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel2);
        prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
        prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
        prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

        return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";
    }
     private void stringReplacedToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string promptValue = Form1.ShowDialog("Find What", "Replace");

    }
```

I want to get values of `textbox` and `textbox2` in other method.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just return an array with the two textbox values.

```
public static string[] ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
{
    Form prompt = new Form()
    {
        Width = 500,
        Height = 150,
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
        Text = caption,
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    };

    Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 10, Text = text };
    Label textLabel2 = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 55, Text = text };
    textLabel2.Text = "Replace with";
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 70, Width = 200 };
    TextBox textBox2 = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 30, Width = 200 };

    Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Replace", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
    confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
    prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
    prompt.Controls.Add(textBox2);
    prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel2);
    prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
    prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
    prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

    return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? new string[] { textBox.Text, textBox2.Text } : null;
}

private void stringReplacedToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] promptValue = Form1.ShowDialog("Find What", "Replace");

    var textBoxValue = promptValue[0];
    var textBox2Value = promptValue[1];
}
```

Comment: but how can i use value of both textbox values in other function on `REPLACE` button click?

Comment: Check my latest modification of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for response.I have copy your code and paste in my code but it show error.Kindly check [LINK](https://i.imgsafe.org/bee9e48391.png)

Comment: I missed the static keyword in my method. Try again now.

Comment: Thank you so much .You great .LOVE YOU BRO :) I have put `static` then its working fine.awesome

Comment: Great! Keep coding and get better :)

Comment: hi..can you help little more pleaseee?

Comment: In case it is related to the above question, yes. Otherwise you should create another question.